# Importing Pages with Python, PyQt, Qt Designer, & QStackedWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm trying to import a page using PyQt and add it to a QStackedWidget created using Qt Designer.  I'd like to not touch the compiled page code nor the compiled MainWindow code.  I can show the MainWindow fine, but I can't seem to import the page and add it my QStackedWidget.

Here is what my MainWindow and page compiled code looks like:

My `mainWindow.py`

```py
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

    try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
    except AttributeError:
        _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    ...
```

My `appInfoPage.py`

```py
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

    try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
    except AttributeError:
        _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

    class Ui_appInfoPage(object):
        def setupUi(self, appInfoPage):
            appInfoPage.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("appInfoPage"))
    ...
```

My main.py

```py
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
    from appInfoPage import Ui_appInfoPage

    class main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.appInfoPage = Ui_appInfoPage()
        self.appInfoPage.setupUi(self.appInfoPage)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.appInfoPage)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.appInfoPage)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      application = QApplication(sys.argv)
      window = main()
      window.show()
      sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

The current code gives me a `AttributeError: 'Ui_appInfopage' object has no attributes 'setObjectName'` error and if I put `self.appInfoPage.setupUi(self)` instead, the page overlaps the MainWindow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the two `Ui_*` classes shows that they are simple wrappers that have a baseclass of `object` - they are not Qt classes.

Instead, they have a `setupUi()` method that requires an instance of a Qt class to be passed as the first argument.

In your `class main.__init__()` you are correctly passing an instance of `QMainWindow` (i.e. `self`) to the `setupUi` method of the inherited `Ui_MainWindow` class. But you are not passing an instance of the correct Qt class to `self.appInfoPage.setupUi`, which is why you are getting the `AtrributeError`.

One way to correct this would be to create a subclass of `Ui_appInfoPage`, and then pass an instance of *that* to your stacked-widget:

```
class AppInfoPage(QWidget, Ui_appInfoPage):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
...

    self.appInfoPage = AppInfoPage(self)
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.appInfoPage)
```

**NB**: I have used `QWidget` for my `AppInfoPage` subclass, but you will obviously need to change that if your `Ui_appInfoPage` is actually based on a different Qt class.

Comment: I have another problem related to this project: I can't seem to set a AppInfoPage QLineEdit text under the actual AppInfoPage class via self.lineEdit.setText('test'), but I am able to set it under the main class using self.appInfoPage.lineEdit.setText('test').  However, I am able to read the QLineEdit under the AppInfoPage class with self.lineEdit.text().  Thank you again.

Comment: @Voltron43. Please start a new question for this, and show the actual code that is causing you problems.